# How to check the CMS Opencart for outgoing connections?

Tags: opencart

Here is the message received today from the host: "Some of the modules of your CMS cause a large number of simultaneous connections on ports 80 and 443" CMS: opencart

Please tell me the program to detect this problem.

Comment: from the top of my head you can run `netstat` in your cli to see the connections made. but I don't think this is what you are looking for. the whole error seems to not make sense. So you have modules that are connecting to other servers? whatever it is, ask the hosting provider to send you a log of all these requests based on which they think its OC modules. if they can share the which part of code is making the request, you can use that to located the modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Some of the modules of your CMS cause a large number of simultaneous connections on ports 80 and 443"

Port 80 is HTTP, port 443 is HTTPS, so what your host is suggesting is that some of your OpenCart Extensions are making requests over HTTP(S) which is likely to be admin pages that use AJAX.

I suggest you ask your web host what requests exactly are being made - this should be available in the HTTP access logs. You will then see what URLs are being requested by these extensions, and that should give you a clue as to which extensions are doing all these requests because it is likely to be their own controllers.

It's most likely that these requests will be happening when you access the admin.

Another possibility, which is very common in my experience, is that the web host are talking nonsense and blaming your website when they are not giving you enough server resources.

An experienced OpenCart developer (you can find many in the [OpenCart Commercial Support Forum](http://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=88)) should be able to tell you exactly what is going on and whether an extension is to blame or whether you should switch web hosts.